# Security Services Unavailable Weblogic

Tags: weblogic

I am trying to start my domain in Weblogic 12.1. It was working fine. today when i tried to restart the domain it gave the following error

> Security Services Not Found. Falied to load Myreal

i have not created a database.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

That error indicates a security subsystem could not initialize correclty. Have you setup a security provider (like ldap, opensso etc) recently ?

Comment: No. I did not setup anything and it was working fine previously. Is there anyway to remove this installation completely from my mac.